# Swift: DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a local PDF to load within a view of an app I am building. I have the PDF's loaded into my images.cassetes folder. I have also gone into targets > info> Document Types and added a PDF as a document type:com.adobe.pdf.

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.

Here is the code for my View Controller:

```
 import UIKit

 class DisplayFirstStepsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentDocument: UIWebView!

    var currentFirstSteps : FirstStep?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource((named: currentFirstSteps!.filename), ofType:"pdf")!)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc!);



    self.currentDocument.loadRequest(request);


    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

It worked in the simulator but not on actual phone. Then I clicked product > clean and now I get this error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I see where the original error was fixed using this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b777normalprocedures"     ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
_webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

However, I am not sure how to convert this to swift from Objective-c OR how to clean up my code to work as is. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
func loadUrl(request:NSURL){
    currentDocument.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: request))
}
func loadData(data:NSData){
    currentDocument.loadData(data, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: nil)
}
if let pdfFileBundleUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("pdfFileName", withExtension: "pdf") {
    loadUrl(pdfFileBundleUrl)
}

if let targetURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("b777normalprocedures", withExtension: "pdf") {
    if let pdfData = NSData(contentsOfURL:targetURL) {
        loadData(pdfData)
        println("Successfully loaded data" )
    } else {
        println("Failed to loading data")
    }
}


let docsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL
docsUrl.absoluteURL!
docsUrl.absoluteString!
docsUrl.path!
```

**Code sample**

You can also make it cache the pdf so it doesn't download it twice as Follow:

First add those two vars to your AppDelegate.swift

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  pdfSample

import UIKit
var loaded = false
var cachedData:NSData? = nil
```

//

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var wv: UIWebView!

    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL

    func loadData(data:NSData){
        cachedData = data
        wv.loadData(data, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: nil)

    }
    func loadPDF(link:String){
        if let pdfOnlineUrl = NSURL(string: link) {
            if let downloadedData = NSData(contentsOfURL: pdfOnlineUrl) {
                let newFolderUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("pdfs")
                var err: NSErrorPointer = nil
                if NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(newFolderUrl.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err) {
                    println("directory successfully created and/or opened")
                    let pdfDestinationUrl = newFolderUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pdfOnlineUrl.lastPathComponent!)
                    if downloadedData.writeToURL(pdfDestinationUrl, atomically: true) {
                        println("pdf saved")
                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: pdfDestinationUrl) {
                            loadData(data)
                            let pdfFile = pdfDestinationUrl.lastPathComponent?.stringByDeletingPathExtension
                            println("Successfully loaded data pdf file named " + pdfFile! )
                            loaded = true
                        } else {
                            println("Failed to load data pdf file: \(pdfDestinationUrl.lastPathComponent?.stringByDeletingPathExtension)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        println("file not saved")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("error creating destination folder / destination folder not found")
                }
            } else {
                println("Failed to download font from URL: " + pdfOnlineUrl.description)
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       if !loaded {
       loadPDF("https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference.pdf")
        } else {
            loadData(cachedData!)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! This worked great. Now I'm off to find out how to better manipulate the files once viewed. A pan and pinch just doesn't give me exactly what I want. Right now it seems a bit cludgy.

Comment: Any idea on what this log message means? I'm getting this (DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory) log message in console. My app works and displays the pdf correctly in my webView, but I'd like to understand this log message?